# SpringBoot Embedded Tomcat NullPointerException

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I've recently started converting an old Spring project to SpringBoot. I was no the original author of this project, so I unfortunately don't have a complete understanding of its configuration.

For the most part, compiling to a jar seems to be working. However, as soon as I open the webpage, Spring has a mapping error.

The stacktrace only contains embedded tomcat code, so I'm not sure where to start debugging this.

> 2016-02-22 10:05:32.472 ERROR 4995 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat]. [localhost].[/]       : Error during mapping
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper(Mapper.java:1008)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:712)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContext.java:499)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContextFacade.java:221)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:427)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:304)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:181)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_74]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_74]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]

The app is being run from Intellij's SpringBoot plugin.
The error occurs upon accessing the default '/' mapping.

Migration steps:

- Add spring-boot-starter-parent to pom.xml
- Import spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-jdbc
- Setup jdbc connection in application.properties instead of tomcat config
- Create main class with @SpringBootApplication, @ImportResource (with my 4 xml files), and @EnableJpaRepositories

It should be noted that switching to SpringBoot worked fine while running within tomcat. It's when I tried compiling to a jar that I ran into this issue.

I've just tried running with Undertow instead of Tomcat, and it seemed to work. Though I'm not running into a "Request method 'POST' not supported. It's happening with a library that I'm using (khs-sherpa), which I'm assuming doesn't support Undertow.

Any help would be very appreciated. Let me know if there is anything else that needs to be in the question.

Comment: Is there a better way to post stack traces?

Comment: Need more details... e.g. configurations... What have you done to migrate... How you run the app... Which url you are trying to access...

Comment: @jny I appologize, thanks for the list of things to include. I tried to say everything that might be relevant, though I may have missed some things.

Comment: What is your Tomcat version number?

Comment: I believe the issue was due to entries in web.xml. I've configured most of those entries in my Application class, and it seems to work now. I wish there was an easier way to debug that.